# Regexp: not equal certain version

Tags: regex, unix, regex-negation

How to specify regex to return all folders except with certain version in its name

For example, I have such structure:

```
/tmp
  |->java-1.9 
  |->libs-2.2.0-prebuild
  |    |-some content
  |->libs-2.2.1-prebuild
  |    |-some content
  |->libs-2.1.2-prebuild
  |    |-some content
```

And I need to get all libs folder name Unix's find command, except folder with certain version in its name (f.g. 2.2.0)

I was trying this command but it does not work

```
find /tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*libs-((?!2\.2\.0).)*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`find`** solution:

```
find /tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex ".*/libs-.*" ! -regex "./libs-2\.2\.0-.*"
```

- `! <expr>` - logical negation operator, gives `True` if `<expr>` is `False`

Comment: Could add a point that `-not` could also be used in place of `!`

Comment: @Inian, `!` is better cause `-not` is not POSIX compliant